# How to change the border size in ComplexHeatmap?

Tags: r, size, border, heatmap

How to change the border size in ComplexHeatmap?

I can add border by setting heatmap_border = TRUE. Is there a way to change the size/width?
Below is a figure with different border size. The inner boder looks thinner than the heatmap border.

I am using R package ComplexHeatmap.

Thanks!

[image: o]

Answer (score 1):

```
Heatmap(as.matrix(snps.cor),name="snps1", cluster_rows = FALSE,cluster_columns  = FALSE,show_row_dend=FALSE,
        show_row_names = FALSE,
        show_column_names = FALSE,
        border = TRUE,column_split = split,row_split=split,
        col = col_fun2,top_annotation = ha,
        column_gap = unit(0, "mm"),row_gap = unit(0, "mm"))
# draw(ht, heatmap_legend_side = "bottom", annotation_legend_side = "bottom")
decorate_heatmap_body("snps1", slice = 12,column_slice = 4, {
  grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = "transparent", col = "black", lwd = 2))
  
})
```

I found I can change the width by decorate_heatmap_body. If there is no slice parameter, only the border of top left slice is changed. I can change the border for speficic slice by adding `slice = 12,column_slice = 4`.

How can I changed the border width for whole heatmap?

[image]